# samba user accounts. specific user permissions vs guest access permissions

Tags: samba, users

can someone please confirm the following.
I would like 2 methods of accessing the same 4 samba folders

1. by me user john, with read/write permissions, accessed via user/pass
2. by any guest with read permissions only.

do i do this by editing the smb.conf file

Create a new user first: sudo useradd samba-guest.
Search your smb.conf for guest account. Set this to samba-guest (guest account = samba-guest).

and then have a second user called john
and then in the smb.conf file, set the access for john to be read/write

will that do it?
thanks

p.s do i need to use chown or anything like that?
p.p.s the information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824745/smb-shares-mix-between-guest-and-user-specific-how-to-config-and-troubleshoot) is relevant?

or is this even possible

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a couple of ways:

**But First**: Remove the ***guest account = samba-guest*** line from smb.conf. There already is a guest account set up by default and it's name is "nobody". You can verify this yourself if you want:

```
testparm -sv /dev/null | grep "guest account"
```

** One way to do this is with a share definition that looks something like this:

```
[Test]
path = /mnt/Test
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
write list = jim
create mask = 0755
```

Just make sure that Test is owned by jim:

```
sudo chown jim /mnt/Test
```

It will be read only to everyone but jim. If your clients are running either Linux or macOS they will always be offered a choice of connecting as anonymous / guest or with a user name. Worse case you can use Connect-to-Server in either OS to force credentials. Windows is the problem child since it will not be prompted to what it sees as a guest share. One way around this is to "map" the "drive" which is the closest thing in Windows to Connect-to-Server.

** Another way is to force a credentials prompt for everyone ( guest ok = no ) but still only allow a write by jim:

```
[Test]
path = /mnt/Test
guest ok = no
read only = yes
write list = jim
create mask = 0755
```

Here the guest user would submit the user samba-guest with it's samba password.

** And remember to add these user(s) to the samba password database:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a jim
sudo smbpasswd -a samba-guest
```